# How to convert bitmap image with 32bit to 16bit color quality in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, image

We have two imagew, first image is captured in WindowsXP for 
32bit color quality and the same is captured in WindowsXP for 16bit color quality.Both images have been saved as bitmap image.But while comparing both, we are observing that hash values are different. Here we are planning to implement the C# code to convert the 32bit color quality image to 16bit color quality image.

Has anyone have worked on such kind of bitmap image comparison issue, Any inputs on this front would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use next

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    gr.DrawImage(yourImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, yourImage.Width, yourImage.Height));
```

`bmp` - will have 16 bit quality