# How to 32 bit rgb to 16 bit rgb on programming language C#?

Tags: c#, rgb, 16-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert bitmap image with 32bit to 16bit color quality in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183767/how-to-convert-bitmap-image-with-32bit-to-16bit-color-quality-in-c)

I have problem.

I need to convert a 32bit RGB image to 16bit RGB using c#.

Can anyone suggest a starting point for me?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Can you post some code or at least expain what you mean by 16-bit and 32-bit RGB?

Comment: Starting point: `System.Drawing` namespace.

Comment: Given that you've likely not tried yet, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378690/convert-24-bit-bmp-to-16-bit - this should get you on your way to an understanding on how. Google is helpful also.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183767/how-to-convert-bitmap-image-with-32bit-to-16bit-color-quality-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Divide each R, G and B value by 2 ^ 16, or 65536 - shifting them 16 bits to the right (this may be a performance hint) - and then recombine the results.

Comment: I came to the point that
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            b = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToByte(textBox1.Text) >> 3);
            MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
            int g = Convert.ToByte(textBox2.Text) >> 2;
            MessageBox.Show(g.ToString());
           byte deneme = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToByte(g) & 7);
           textBox3.Text=deneme.ToString();
           byte deneme2 = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToByte(deneme) << 5);         

           byte bir = Convert.ToByte(b + deneme2);
           MessageBox.Show(bir.ToString());